# Django - Return full_name from Profile model which has relation with Django User model in other model

Tags: django

I created `Book`, `Book_stat` a `Profile` model which has relation with `Django User` Model, i am trying to display `Book title` and `full_name from Profile` as default **str** return string from `Book_stat`

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from decimal import Decimal

# Create your models here.
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name

class Book_stat(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=Decimal('0.00'))
    like = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.book.title # here i would like to return book title + full_name from Profile Model
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Book, Book_stat, Profile
# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Book)
admin.site.register(Book_stat)
admin.site.register(Profile)
```

When i click on `Book_stat` in my django admin page i would like to display `Book title` and `Profile full_name` as title's in my `Book_stat list`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    def __str__(self):
        return self.book.title +' '+ self.user.profile.full_name
```

try this hope you will get it

Comment: Thanks it worked, i have a doubt whether user has profile instance or profile has user instance i.e. `user.profile` or `profile.user` and how they are related when i use `OneToOneField`

Comment: that depends on how are you accessing it, mostly from which model you want to get the value, always look for the model->field->model->field relation, it goes like that

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

In your Profile model add related_name like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

And in your BookStat model:

```
class Book_stat(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=Decimal('0.00'))
    like = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.book.title + " - " + self.user.profile.full_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Book_stat(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2,     default=Decimal('0.00'))
    like = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.book.title) + " : " + str(self.user.get_full_name())  ## changes done here
```